# Load test server using PHP script?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress

I guess this pretty vague question *could* be classified as a programming one. I did consider whether it belonged in the Ask Ubuntu / WordPress Development / Linux Administration communities- but of course I don't like to spam either. Apologies up front if I made a huge mistake and caused you to have a bad day.

Take a linux server, it has a number of WordPress sites on it, and we can already guess that the dominant interpreted language is PHP when you consider the above scenario.

These are not live sites, they are simply sites copied from a production server.

I want to simulate random traffic to all of them at once to see if the server can handle the load. Perhaps a PHP script run from the command line can do this?

Just looking for ideas at this stage.

I have tried https://www.blitz.io/ - works wonderfully, however just one site at a time as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Maybe you could make your own python webcrawler. Something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFas42HBtMg an then do so for all of sites. Just thinking out loud

Comment: @SuperDJ bookmarked for the morning. Never visited python before. Could be interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://jmeter.apache.org/ will do the job but need way more time to configure than blitz.io

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I'll have a more indepth look in the morning. That page does look rather old fashioned so I'm just wondering how relevant it is - Does look complicated I see what you mean by way more time to configure..